# Backbone Collection method return subset of self

Tags: backbone.js, subclass, method-chaining

Hi I am using Backbonejs, I have a example collection

```
var MyCollection=Backbone.Collection.extend({
    init:function(options){xxx},
    getPageNumber:function(){this.length/100},
    myfilter:function(){},
});
```

The problem is I want to add this myfilter function, that filter out the collection, and return the same type "myCollection", so that I can then call getPageNumber(). like this:

```
collection.myfilter(cb).getPageNumber();
```

The default filter function in backbone return a simple array, not the Backbone.Collection Object. so is the underscorejs.filter.(which essensially is the same as Backbone.collection.filter). I am wondering if there is an easy way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you simply incorporate the filter into the getPageNumber method - getPageNumber: function() { return this.myFilter().length / 100; }

Comment: That is one way to go, but I was just wondering if there is a more elegant solution for my other functions. I even thought about initialize a collection, then add into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can refresh your original collection using [reset](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset)

```
  myfilter:function(){
         var result = yourFilterLogicHere...

         this.reset(result);
         return this;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!, this is almost what I want now, except I didn't want to replace the collection with the filtered one, I wanted to created a shallow copy of the collection. I end up just calling the constructor